# Solr 8.9.0 retrieval query in different sceanrios

Tags: java, solr, fuzzy-search

Enviornment - solr-8.9.0, java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS

I have loaded following .csv file in solr with default configurations.

```
Admission_number,Name,Fathers_name,DOA
099159,A AABSANANDHA REDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951      ---Name
099150,A AABSANANDHAREDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951       ---Missing space
099151,A REDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951                  ---Missing components
099152,A AABSANANDHA. REDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951     ---Split fields by .
099153,A AABSANANDH REDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951       ---Spelling differences@1 character missing
799163,A AABSANAND REDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951        ---Spelling differences@2 character missing
729173,A AABSANAN REDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951         ---Spelling differences@3 character missing
729183,A AABSANA REDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951          ---Spelling differences@4 character missing
729154,Dr. A AABSANANDHA REDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951  ---Titles and Honorifics
729155,A REDDY AABSANANDHA,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951      ---Out of order components
099155,A GENDHI BAKER,MD YOUSUF ALI,30/12/1981
```

I want to do fuzzy search for column name with following requirements - a. Missing space b.Missing components c.Split fields by '.' d. Spelling differences e.Titles and Honorifics f. Out of order components

To do this i have passed query in 2 ways to solr

```
1. http://localhost:8983/solr/start/select?indent=on&wt=json&q=Name:'A AABSANANDHA REDDY~'
```

Cons - Above case gives almost all loaded documents in output Eg. It is giving document with name as 'A GENDHI BAKER'. These two names (A AABSANANDHA REDDY,A GENDHI BAKER) are entirely different, only 'A' is similar. It should not come in output.

```
2. http://localhost:8983/solr/start/select?indent=on&wt=json&q=Name:'A~1' AND Name:'AABSANANDHA~' AND Name:'REDDY~'
```

Pros - It is giving only relevant results.

Cons - But it is not fulfilling all cases. Following requirements are not fulfilled - a. Missing space b.Missing components c. Spelling differences with variation of more than 1 character.

Only few cases are comming in output.  a. Split fields by '.' b. Spelling differences with variation of 1 character c.Titles and Honorifics d. Out of order components

Output for case 2--

```
099159,A AABSANANDHA REDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951      ---Name
099152,A AABSANANDHA. REDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951     ---Split fields by .
099153,A AABSANANDH REDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951       ---Spelling differences@1 character missing
729154,Dr. A AABSANANDHA REDDY,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951  ---Titles and Honorifics
729155,A REDDY AABSANANDHA,MD YOUSUF ALI,21/03/1951      ---Out of order components
```

What will be the rest query request so that above mentioned cases comes in output?

Comment: This will depend on your field types. Define field types that match each of your requirements, and search in those fields by themselves. To get fuzzy matches that only consider the whole field, use a `string` field instead of a regular text field, to get fields split by `.`, add a tokenizer that splits by that character; for the rest of them - define the exact requirements and create field types that maps those requirements.

Comment: @MatsLindh ...Thankx for reply, Can u direct me to some example/links?

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/understanding-analyzers-tokenizers-and-filters.html - this have the different tokenizers and filters that are available by default